# Delete image from repeater control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater control to display images. Below every images I have placed a button for deleting the image. I want the image to get removed from the repeater control on pressing that delete button. I tried everywhere to find this but i didn't get the solution. Thanks in advance. 
Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="FileRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="float: left; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid gray;" ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Width="80px" Text="Delete" CommandName="delete" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


protected void RepeaterCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)   
{       
    RepeaterItem itemToRemove = e.Item;
    String sessionItemToRemove = itemToRemove.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("%c", sessionItemToRemove);
    Session.Remove(sessionItemToRemove);     
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("images"));
    List<String> images = new List<string>(list.Count());

    foreach (string item in list)
    {
        images.Add(String.Format("~/Images/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
    }

        FileRepeater.DataSource = images;
        FileRepeater.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Heres one thought... hyperlink that to a removePic.aspx page and pass in its id. On that page, remove the image from the database and then redirect  back to your original page. Thats how I usually do it

Comment: Where is the code for binding the repeater located at, `Page_Load`?

Comment: surely it should be `<asp:Repeater..`

Comment: Just remove corresponding row from the datasource (datatable?) and rebind the repeater

Comment: @logixlogist I am not binding the image from database. I am binding it from a folder in my local pc.

Comment: @karlAnderson Yes. Its at Page_Load

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter I am not binding the image from database. I am binding it from a folder in my local pc.

Comment: When u click Delete do you want to remove actual image from the folder as well or just from the repeater? Also can u post code where you bind repeater to the folder?

Comment: @yuriy Galanter I want to delete the image from the folder. Because I am binding the image in the repeater from the folder only. So if the image get removed from the folder it will ultimately get removed from the repeater too when page load event is called.  And I changed the code. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: You dont have to delete it from the folder, just delete it from your List (so you dont have to reload the List again) and rebind Repeater to to the List.

Comment: @yuriy Galanter How to delete it from the list?